# what's the utility of using Activator.CreateInstance method

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, design-patterns

what is the difference between these two snippets of code.
I want to know why he use all that amount of code at the second snippet while he could just use simple new to create an instance of DataTable;

```
1) var dt = new DataTable();
2) var dt = ObjectBuilder.Instance<DataTable>();
```

.

```
public class ObjectBuilder
{
    #region ObjectBuilder Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Instances this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T Instance<T>() where T : class
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Instances the specified arguments.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="arguments">The arguments.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T Instance<T>(params object[] arguments) where T : class
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's it got to do with Activator.CreateInstance?

Comment: sorry I didn't supply more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second should be very clear to you. It creates an instance of a `DataTable` type.

The first also does the same but using the `ObjectBuilder` component. This is a framework used for creating a dependency injection systems. It uses a pipeline of strategies that allows you to customize the creation (and destruction) process. For instance you can automatically assign values to properties and fields or take various actions based on attributes declared on members. See [Design of ObjectBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff709825.aspx) for more details.